# ember.js using host from ApplicationAdapter in a specific Adapter

Tags: ember.js, adapter

I have the host of the remote server defined in the general ApplicationAdapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8000/rest'
});
```

In a specific adapter I'm overriding findQuery (to fetch more data), but using `this.host` gives me `undefined`

```
App.TestAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    findQuery: function (store, type, query) {
        var testsURL;
        testsURL = this.host + "/sessions/" + query.sessionId + "/tests";
        delete query.sessionId;
        return this.ajax(testsURL, 'GET', {
            data: query
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend() creates a new subclass, so your first code block is creating a new App.ApplicationAdapter subclass with your specified host property. Your second code block is just extending the DS.RestAdapter class again, which doesn't have the host property that you set.

To fix this, you need to extend App.ApplicationAdapter:

```
App.TestAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    findQuery: function (store, type, query) {
        var testsURL;
        testsURL = this.host + "/sessions/" + query.sessionId + "/tests";
        delete query.sessionId;
        return this.ajax(testsURL, 'GET', {
            data: query
        });
    }
});
```